# OPcache counts cache hits, but no performance boost

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching

I have an Apache2 web server configured on my VPS, and it works well. The server hosts a WordPress blog and until now I was using some WP Super Cache plugin. I wanted to switch to OPcache. The new cache is working, at least I think so. Here's some output of the phpinfo script:

```
Zend OPcache
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup     OK
Shared memory model     mmap
Cache hits  46539
Cache misses    455
Used memory     34701752
Free memory     99515976
Wasted memory   0
Interned Strings Used memory    4194296
Interned Strings Free memory    8
Cached scripts  454
Cached keys     507
Max keys    7963
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts     0
```

As you can see I have many cache hits, but the problem is that the cache doesn't work. I mean, maybe it is working, but I don't see any performance boost.

I tried to see how many request per second I can get when I issue the following command:

```
$ ab -kc 10 -n 1000 https://wp.blog.tld/
```

When I disable OPcache, I get around 4/s. When OPcache is enabled, I get the exact same number, which is around 4/s. In contrast when I disable OPcache and enable WP Super Cache, I get close to 200/s. So what is wrong with OpCache? Does it cache or not or maybe is something wrong with my server's configuration?

```
VPS:
Debian stable

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Feb 24 2017 18:40:28

PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

OPcache is cache for precompiled scripts - it's removing necessity to compile each php file on each request. It doesn't mean it will magically boost php performance(in some cases it can, in other there can be no difference). Did you restarted your apache if you are using php plugin with it? Also WP Super Cache or W3 Total Cache are whole different plugins witch more sophisticated options.

Comment: Yes, of course I restarted Apache after enabling the plugin. So I simply can't get close to ~200/s requests with OPcache? Should I use WP Super Cache + OPcache?

Comment: Yes. I guess just your apache and/or hardware is bottleneck. Try checking on nginx maybe with php-fpm.